# Homeomorphisms and Borel Sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, functions

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous bijective function with a continuous inverse. Then, is it true that $f$ will map Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ to Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? I'm not sure on how to prove/think about this statement since a Borel set will belong to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets, but we cannot necessarily express a Borel sets with unions/intersections of Borel sets. What would be a nice way to think about this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: Show that the inverse image of any sigma algebra on $Y$ is also a sigma algebra. Also Homeomorphism preserves topological properties such as open and closed.

Comment: I think what uou meant to say is that we cannot (in general) express Borel sets as countable unions or intersections of OPEN sets. A homeomorphism $ f:X\to Y$ will map a structure based entirely on the topology of $X$ to the corresponding structure based on the topology of $Y$. Homeomorphic spaces can be considered topologically to be  the same space, just drawn with different colored inks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since the inverse of $f$ is continuous then $f$ is an open map. And since $f$ is a bijection then it preserves arbitrary unions and intersections of subsets and also preserves relative complements. And since every Borel set can be expressed as a combination of (countable) unions,  intersections and relative complements of open sets then here you go.

Comment: The last statement is false, a Boret set is not always a "combination" of countable unions or intersection of open sets.

Comment: @Phil-W Of course I forgot about relative complements. Updated the answer.

Comment: this is still false, all Borel sets cannot be obtained this way. You have to use a transfinite induction to get all of them through those operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is true. By definition, Borel set is generated by open intervals, and 1-dim open set is countable union of open intervals.